# swapping pairs in arrays recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

Trying to swap pairs in an array recursively, managed to get it iteratively.
How would I implement the swap part recursively? I think I have most of it correct!  If there is an odd number, the last one stays the same. I don't want to have a helper swap function if possible.

```
pairSwap = function(arr) {
      var newArray = []
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        var current = arr[i];
        var next = arr[i + 1]
        if (next !== undefined) {
          newArray.push(next)
        }
        if (current !== undefined) {
          newArray.push(current)
        };
      };
      return newArray;
    }

    console.log(pairSwap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
    pairSwapRecursive = function(arr) {

      if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
      } else {
        //swap the first and second:
        return (swap ? ) + pairSwapRecursive(arr.slice(2))

      }


    }

    console.log(pairSwapRecursive([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) //should return [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]

//something similar in Java:

    // public String swapPairs(String s) {
    //      if (s.length() < 2)
    //           return s;
    //      else
    //           return swap(s.charAt(0), s.charAt(1)) + swapPairs(s.substring(2));
    // }
```

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting a helper function?

Comment: @torazaburo pure recursion :) this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to have a helper swap function if possible.

And you don't need it - simply return the second and the first element and you're done:

```
var pairSwapRecursive = function(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    }

    return [arr[1], arr[0]].concat(pairSwapRecursive(arr.slice(2)));
};
```

So as any other recursive algorithm it:

1. Does some little chunk of work. In this case - it is to return an array with 2 first elements swapped.
2. Invokes itself with the rest

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/am8rz1jx/

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of the @zerkms solution, here's a version which reverses chunks of any length:

```
function reverse_chunks(n) {

  return function _reverse_chunks(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) return arr;
    return arr.slice(0, n).reverse().concat(_reverse_chunks(arr.slice(n)));
  };

}

reverser = reverse_chunks(2);
reverser([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If you'd like to make it a bit more semantic and readable, and moving to ES6:

```
function reverse_chunks(n) {

  return function _reverse_chunks(arr) {
    var [head, tail] = [arr.slice(0, n), arr.slice(n)];
    if (!arr.length) return [];
    return [ ...head.reverse(), ..._reverse_chunks(tail) ];
  };

}
```

If you're so inclined, you could also parameterize this with the function to permute the elements of each chunk:

```
function permute_chunks(n = 2, permute = arr => arr.reverse()) {

  return function _permute_chunks(arr) {
    var [head, tail] = [arr.slice(0, n), arr.slice(n)];
    if (!arr.length) return [];
    return [ ...permute(head), ..._permute_chunks(tail) ];
  };

}
```

Then

```
permuter = permute_chunks(5, arr => arr.sort());
```

would sort each chunk of five elements.